# PHP MySQLi Query within Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm in the process of updating from MySQL to MySQLi and have come across an issue I'm not sure how to handle with MySQLi/prepared statements.

In my previous code, I had a query within a query:

```
while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    //CLEAR VARIABLES
    $REMINDER_TIME = '';
    $REMINDER_USER_ID = '';

    //STORE DATA
    $REMINDER_TIME = $record['REMINDER_TIME'];
    $REMINDER_USER_ID = $record['USER_ID'];

    //LOCALIZE TIMES    
    $REMINDER_TIME = new DateTime($REMINDER_TIME);
    $REMINDER_TIME->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($user_timezone));

    //GET USER NAME
    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL FROM TABLE_users WHERE USER_ID='$REMINDER_USER_ID'");

    while ($record1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) 
    {
        //CLEAR VARIABLES
        $REMINDER_USER_FIRST = '';
        $REMINDER_USER_LAST = '';
        $REMINDER_USER_EMAIL = '';

        //STORE DATA
        $REMINDER_USER_FIRST = $record1['FIRST_NAME'];
        $REMINDER_USER_LAST = $record1['LAST_NAME'];
        $REMINDER_USER_EMAIL = $record1['EMAIL'];
    }

    $tableRow .= '<tr>
                 <td class="tall">'.$REMINDER_TIME->format('F j, Y').'<br />'.$REMINDER_TIME->format('g:ia T').'</a></td>
                 <td class="tall">'.$REMINDER_USER_FIRST.' '.$REMINDER_USER_LAST.'<br />('.$REMINDER_USER_EMAIL.')</td>
                 </tr>';
}
```

However, with my prepared statements, I'm not sure how to run a query within a query:

```
$result = $stmt -> get_result();

while ($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    //CLEAR VARIABLES
    $REMINDER_TIME = '';
    $REMINDER_USER_ID = '';

    //STORE DATA
    $REMINDER_TIME = $row['REMINDER_TIME'];
    $REMINDER_USER_ID = $row['USER_ID'];

    //LOCALIZE TIMES    
    $REMINDER_TIME = new DateTime($REMINDER_TIME);
    $REMINDER_TIME->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($user_timezone));

    //_____QUERY WOULD GO HERE_____

    $tableRow .=    '<tr>
    <td class="tall">'.$REMINDER_TIME->format('F j, Y').'<br />'.$REMINDER_TIME->format('g:ia T').'</a></td>
    <td class="tall">'.$REMINDER_USER_FIRST.' '.$REMINDER_USER_LAST.'<br />('.$REMINDER_USER_EMAIL.')</td>
    </tr>';
}

$stmt->close();
```

Is it possible to do this with prepared statements?  I basically need to hit the database to get data in a secondary query based on values received during the first query.  Thank you!

Comment: I think your problem is you think you're doing a query in a query. But you're not. You're just running a query and then you're using PHP to loop through the results. You can just do a new query while looping through the results. The looping is done in PHP not in MySQL. MySQL doesn't matter how many query you're doing while looping through the results since it has nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.  Should I issue the `$stmt -> close()` right after `$result = $stmt -> get_result();` ?

Comment: Well, I've never really used the close function (I'm using PDO anyway). But you'd kill your results if you don't fetch them before. The comments of mysqli_stmt_close are stating you should rather use `$stmt->reset()`. http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.reset.php

Comment: Can you tell me why you're using MySQLi and not directly PDO? (PDO has a cleaner and better integration of Prepared Statements, fyi)

Comment: Can you inclue in your post the first sql query ? It is a really bad idea to do a query inside a loop. You probably could rewrite this code and do only one query to retrieve all informations you need (with a join query for example)

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Thanks for your feedback!  Honestly, I just prefer MySQLi for my purposes.

Comment: @ImadMoqaddem  Thank you for the reply!  Sure, the initial query is:  `SELECT * FROM TABLE_logs_reminders WHERE REQUEST_ID=? ORDER BY REMINDER_TIME`

Comment: Did the answer provided solve your issue ?

Comment: @ImadMoqaddem  Hello!  I had to be out today but am going to try your solution tomorrow.  Makes a lot of sense.  Will come back here and let you know / mark answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing queries inside a loop is a bad practice and should be avoided, because of performance issues.

Given the code and query you posted, I suggest you to modify your first sql statement:

```
SELECT a.REMINDER_TIME, a.USER_ID, b.FIRST_NAME, b.LAST_NAME, b.EMAIL
FROM TABLE_logs_reminders a
LEFT JOIN table_users b on a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE REQUEST_ID=?
ORDER BY a.REMINDER_TIME
```

This will fetch the data you need, in one single request, avoiding several calls to your DBMS.
Then, in your php code, you can access the user columns without a new query:

```
//_____QUERY WOULD GO HERE_____
// No need for a query
$REMINDER_USER_FIRST = $record1['FIRST_NAME'];
$REMINDER_USER_LAST = $record1['LAST_NAME'];
$REMINDER_USER_EMAIL = $record1['EMAIL'];
```

There are some good tutorials about joins you should read.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I tried this query but SQL is saying there is a syntax error near LEFT JOIN.  Here is the query: `SELECT a.REMINDER_TIME, a.USER_ID, b.FIRST_NAME, b.LAST_NAME, b.EMAIL FROM TABLE_logs_reminders a WHERE REQUEST_ID=? ORDER BY a.REMINDER_TIME LEFT JOIN TABLE_users b ON a.USER_ID = b.USER_ID;`

Comment: I just edited my answer. The order by clause must be after the join.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  Unfortunately I'm still getting a syntax error.  Strange.

Comment: OK - I think I fixed it.  The WHERE clause also had to go at the end.

Comment: yes ! I edited the answer. I copy / pasted your original query and completely forget to move these clauses...